# check my own file type in vim

Tags: vim

After reading usr_43 in VIM manual, I created ~/.vim/ftplugin

The manual said to check my runtimepath, the result

```
runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim73,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after
```

Is the ftplugin under the runtimepath, or do I need to add '~/.vim/ftplugin' into the runtimepath?

And then I tried to detect sql3 files:

```
vim ~/.vim/ftplugin/sqlte3.vim

if exists("b:did_ftplugin")                                                                         
    echo "yes : did_ftpplugin"                                                                            
    finish                                                                                          
elseif                                                                                              
    echo "no : did_ftplugin"                                                                         
endif                                                                                               

let b:did_ftplugin = 1                                                                              

if did_filetype()   
    echo "yes : did_filetype"                                                                                    
    finish                                                                                          
elseif                                                                                              
    echo "no : do file type"                                                                         
endif   

if getline(1) =~ '^#!*[/\\]sqlite3\>'                                                               
    setf sql3                                                                                       
    echo "sqlite3 file"                                                                             
elseif                                                                                              
    echo "not sqlite3 file"                                                                         
endif
```

after that I did 'vim ~/test.sql3'

I thought  to get some output to verify my workflow, but I get nothing.

How do I get the output from ~/.vim/ftplugin/sqlte3.vim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filetype plugin is a wrong place to put code like

```
if getline(1) =~ '^#!*[/\\]sqlite3\>'
    setf sql3
    echo "sqlite3 file"
elseif
```

What you should do is to add this to `ftdetect/sql3.vim`:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile * :if getline(1)=~#'^#!.*[/\\]sqlite3\>' | set ft=sql3.vim | endif
```

. Also note that if you want to have `sql3` filetype, then ftplugin must also be named `sql3.vim`, not `sqlite3.vim` like in your example. Filename of ftdetect plugin does not really matter, this is just an agreement that for ftdetect files detecting one filetype their name should match detected filetype.

Answer (score 2):

The sql3 is not an automatically detect filetype. You have to add an [autocommand](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocommand) in the [ftdetect](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#ftdetect) dir. Something like:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.sql3        set filetype=sql3
```

Than your workflow should work fine.

Comment: thanks. I created .vim/ftdetect/sql3.vim and add 'au BufRead....' into it. I restart vim and open samle.sql3. From the bottom I just saw "sample.sql3 1L, 19C". How do I know it execute ftplugin/sqlte3.vim?

Comment: Try to set a global variable with let g:my_variable='foo' or try to use echoerr.

Comment: or use `:scriptnames` to see what scripts have been loaded.